# Google Ads – Show youtube ad only on placements

Tags: google-adsense, advertising, youtube

I have created a youtube ad video that I only want to show on certain videos (Placements) and nowhere else. For that I have created a new campaign in ad sense and then went to Content -> Placements and added a bunch of videos. However I keep getting charged for my video showing up on a lot of other places.

In fact 99% of my budget goes to these non-sense places that have nothing to do with my advertisement and that are absolutely useless to me. Some seem to be of Type Mobile applications, some seem to be of type Site other of Type YouTube channel.

I don't want any of this:
[image: ad sense list of Where ads showed]

I also went to to Settings and Networks and tried to disable YouTube search results and Video partners, but my settings are greyed out and I can't change them.

[image: Ad sense grayed out network settings]

I tried googling this but I seem to keep missing the right keywords and I can't find anything useful. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Ok I've found this concerning mobile apps: https://surfsideppc.com/exclude-mobile-apps-in-google-ads/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So it turns out that you cannot disable Display Networks anymore. You can however add googleadsense_without_youtube.com to the exclude list which has the same effect for now. See: https://youtu.be/FhNG72XqfCw.

To block the mobile apps you can add all mobile categories to the exclude list. See: https://surfsideppc.com/exclude-mobile-apps-in-google-ads/.

I also set my add to only show on desktop for now.

With both those settings and after waiting 24 hours my campaign is doing fine now.

As a positive side effect the first day drove the view counter really high for a limited amount of money (~10$ for 1000 views), which makes the video look a bit more professional. So the display network seems to be a good legal way drive up view counts should one ever need that. But the effect on sales was useless.